# How to implement youtube search using the youtube API

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

So I'm pretty new to using android studio and building android apps in general. I'm trying to implement the Youtube API and one of the things i'm trying to do is implement search functionality.

So far when it comes to tutorials, I know how to play a hardcoded video with the youtube player, but actually searching a video by keywords is where i'm stuck.

There's not many useful tutorials when it comes to the searching functionality, so any help would be appreciated on how exactly to do this, or some steps that can set me on the right path.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this [repo](https://github.com/abhi5658/search-youtube) will be of use to you...

I would suggest reading over the API [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) as well

Comment: I think I downloaded that repo a couple of days ago but it didn't really work

Comment: Can you provide more information? What didnt work? Do you have a stack trace? What tutorials have you tried?

Comment: The app crashes as soon as I try to search something. There's not really any tutorials online on how to implement this on android studio.